# Runtime Workflow in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, workflow-foundation

I need to create an ASP.NET application that will allow user to create the workflow on the fly and implement it. The user should be able to create the workflow as we create a UML class diagram in case tool. That means user should have an interface to drag drop multiple workflow objects and setting various steps and process.

I will be using:
C# 4.0 ASP.NET, .NET 2010

I need to know how to provide such functionality and which tool I should use for allowing the user to create such runtime workflow and save.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To run workflow foundation designer on the web you will need to look toward XBAP hosting of the WF runtime. Checkout [mtaulty's blog](http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2006/11/22/8981.aspx).